# Added angle formula to solve this indefinite integral $\int\frac{2\cos x-\sin x}{3\sin x+5\cos x }\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, proof-explanation, indefinite-integrals

Starting from this very nice question [Integrate $\int\frac{2\cos x-\sin x}{3\sin x+5\cos x }\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733361/integrate-int-frac2-cos-x-sin-x3-sin-x5-cos-x-dx) and the relative answers, I would to understand because this integral $$\int\frac{2\cos x-\sin x}{3\sin x+5\cos x }\,dx \tag 1$$
must be split thus:

$$\int \frac{2\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{3\sin{x}+5\cos{x}} \; dx=\color{red}{\int A\left(\frac{3\sin{x}+5\cos{x}}{3\sin{x}+5\cos{x}}\right) +B \left(\frac{ 3\cos{x}-5\sin{x}}{3\sin{x}+5\cos{x}}\right)\; dx}$$
or it can be splitted in a different way.

Using the added angle formula (for numerator and denominator of the $(1)$) $$a\sin x+b\cos x=\lambda \sin (x+\phi)$$ if $\lambda=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan \phi=b/a \ $ or $$a\sin x+b\cos x=\lambda \cos (x+\varphi)$$ with $\tan \varphi=-a/b \ $ is it possible to obtain the same result?

Comment: $2\cos x-\sin x=-\sqrt5\sin(x-\arctan2)$ and $3\sin x+5\cos x=\sqrt{34}\sin(x+\arctan(5/3))$, and I'm not immediately convinced that this rewriting will be of much use in simplifying the integral

Comment: @user170231 In the meantime, thank you for your comment, which I have appreciated. But for the $3\sin x+5\cos x$ I will use the $a\sin x+b\cos x=\lambda \cos (x+\varphi)$.

Comment: @Ty. Hi, meanwhile, I can't tell if the split is as unique as the one I highlighted in red. It was just a curiosity because I'd have the derivative of the denominator at the numerator less than the sign but I wouldn't have the term in $x$ less than the coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I=\int\frac{2\cos x-\sin x}{3\sin x+5\cos x }\,dx $ 
$2\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt5 \cos(x+a) $, where $\tan a=1/2$ and $ 3\sin x+5\cos x=\sqrt{34}\cos(x-b) $, where $\tan b=3/5$ 
$I=\int \frac{\sqrt 5 \cos(x+a) } {\sqrt{34}\cos(x-b)} \, dx$ Substitute $t=x-b$ so that 
$I=\sqrt{5/34}\int \frac{\cos(t+a+b) } {\cos t}\, dt$
The integrand is now: $\cos(a+b) - \tan t\sin(a+b) $
 Can you take it from here?

Comment: My $\infty$ thank you. I think that this way is more complicated.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You are welcome. This way  isn't complicated. It only involves calculating $\cos (a+b) $. Given $ \tan a, \tan b$, we can find $\sin, \cos $ and after finding $\sin (a+b) $, we can find $\cos (a+b) $. Why do you think that it's complicated?

Comment: @Sebastiano: What I would do is imagine a rt. angled triangle (for angle $a$), then its perp. is $1$,base is $2$ and hence hypot. is $\sqrt 5$. Hence we can find $cos a$, $sin a$ etc. Similarly for angle $b$. You don't have to do $\sin(arctan (1/2)+arc tan (3/5))$

Comment: Why there are roots square $\cos \theta=\pm 1/\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$, $\sin \theta=\pm \tan \theta/\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$ and the choice of angle depends on the coordinates of the point. I don't really like it that much. It was just a thought of mine.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I thought about it and it turns out that you really don't have to worry about signs here . The reason is: arc tan (3/5) lies either lies in first quadrant or in 3rd. My point is that therefore, $ sin $ and $cos $ both have same sign. Hence, keeping in mind that there is mode sign on $\ln |\cos (x-b) |$, you need not worry about plus /minus. And this makes the calculations a whole lot simpler than you think.

Comment: I have always appreciated   in every community the correct answers of the users. You're right but the question is relative for students of high school. It is necessary one hour to have the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have
$$
\int\frac{a\cos x+b\sin x}{c\cos x+d\sin x}\,dx
$$
(with $ad-bc\ne0$, to avoid trivial cases) you can indeed write the denominator as $k\cos(x+\varphi)$ and do the substitution $y=x+\varphi$, so the numerator becomes
$$
a\cos\varphi\cos y-a\sin\varphi\sin y+b\cos\varphi\sin y-b\sin\varphi\cos y
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{k}\int\Bigl((a\cos\varphi-b\sin\varphi)-(a\sin\varphi-b\cos\varphi)\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}\Bigr)\,dy
$$
which is elementary.

On the other hand, determining $\varphi$ is usually not possible explicitly and, at the end of the day, this is essentially the same as the metod outlined in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much....$\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for @Koro: Yes with some calculus I obtain:

$$\int \left(\cos \left(a+b\right)-\tan \left(t\right)\sin \left(a+b\right)\right)dt=t\cos \left(a+b\right)+\sin \left(a+b\right)\ln \left|\cos \left(t\right)\right|+k, \quad k\in\mathbb R$$

Hence,

$$\int\frac{2\cos x-\sin x}{3\sin x+5\cos x }dx=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{5}{34}}\left[(x-b)\cos \left(a+b\right)+\sin \left(a+b\right)\ln \left|\cos \left(x-b\right)\right|\right]+k=$$

But $a=\arctan (1/2)$ and $b=\arctan (3/5)$. But I will have many calculus having,
$$\cos(\arctan (1/2)+\arctan (3/5))=\dotsb$$
$$\sin(\arctan (1/2)+\arctan (3/5))=\dotsb$$
$$(x-\arctan (3/5))=\dotsb, \quad \cos(x-\arctan (3/5))=\dotsb$$

I think that it takes a lot of time for this way.....to obtain the solution.